# Newest page is acting like the Active page intermittently

Tags: bug, question-lists

For the last week or so occasionally I'll see a question where the user card from the preview does not match the user who asked the question, like this one that just happened:

[image]

As you can see, `newest` is highlighted, but it is showing me the active user, not the OP. The URL that I am on when this happens is

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b
```

This doesn't happen often and not really stopping anything but I though I should mention it.  Also, if I refresh the page, the active post goes away and I'm back to just seeing the newest activity.